# Кроссбраузерность в процентом соотношении

Tags: html, css

У меня возникла идея, как проверять сайты на кроссбраузерность.

Что нужно? Несколько виртуальных машин, на которых будут установлены все возможные браузеры. Хостинг, на котором будет располагаться наш сервис. Из себя он будет представлять обычный сайт с полем ввода url и множеством чекбоксов для выбора браузеров, на которых нужно проверить сайт.

Пользователь вводит url, нажимает на кнопку ok, данные передаются серверу, который в свою очередь обрабатывает данные, открывает на виртальных машинах нужные браузеры с сайтом указанным в url, скриншотит во всех вариантах все страницы, обрабатывает все скриншоты на соответствие друг к другу, это соотношение будет выражаться в %.

После обработки данных пользователь должен увидеть % кроссбраузерности и скриншоты в разных браузерах.

Вопрос: есть ли уже такой сервис, если да, то киньте ссылку, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

http://browsershots.org/ без % конечно, но суть я думаю что ясна.